# Console.log not working when testing regex

Tags: javascript, regex, dom

Can someone explain why my console log is not working?

Every time I select the file for verification to see if anything shows in the console nothing happens

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  document.getElementById('file').onchange = function() {

    var extPermitidas = ['txt'];
    var extArquivo = this.value.split('.').pop();

    if (typeof extPermitidas.find(function(ext) {
        return extArquivo == ext;
      }) == 'undefined') {
      alert('The file cannot be used because its extension is not allowed!');
      return;
    } else {
      var file = this.files[0];

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function(progressEvent) {


        // By lines
        var lines = this.result.split('\n');
        let N = /^(N1\d{14}.{78}|N9\d{14}.{14}\d{6})$/;

        for (var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
          if (N.test(lines[line]) == N) {
            console.log("valid file");
          } else {
            console.log("invalid file");
          }
        }
      };
      reader.readAsText(file);
    }
    alert('file successfully validated!');
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file" />
```

**EDIT**

Could it be a problem in the conditional `if (N.test(lines[line]) == N)`?

Comment: Wrap your parameters with `'` to form a String in the `console.log()`

Comment: Missing quotes. I made and updated a snippet

Comment: Voting to close since the issue is _caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: Did you try to put a `console.log` at the top of the function? Just to see if the event is being fired?

Comment: oh yeah I actually forget to add that but that is not the actual problem

Comment: The strings in the console.logs were not quoted

Comment: Where is `this.files` coming from?  If `file` is invalid, the `onload` handler won't be fired.  Try logging `this.files`.

Comment: The snippet works! It reads a text file and tests the lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a function context issue.  Try changing `var file = this.files[0];` to `var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];`.

`this` can sometimes be tricky since its value is determined by how a function is called (runtime binding).  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Edit:
The conditional `if (N.test(lines[line]) == N)` is strange.  The `test()` method executes a search for a match between a regular expression and a specified string and returns true or false.  So, you don't need to compare the return of test to `== N`.  Plus, you [almost always want to use triple equals (===).](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness)

Comment: Switch to `var file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];`

Comment: But if i put the console.log at the beginning  it triggers it

Comment: Can you update the code in your answer to reflect how it looks now?  I don't understand how putting the console.log at the beginning would trigger anything in this case.

Comment: I just added it after the ```var lines```

Comment: So you think that removing the ```N``` is going to work?

Comment: Try it out.  If you've proven that you can call `console.log` from within the `onload` function, then the issue has to be your regex.  For that, I would recommend using https://regexr.com/ to validate the functionality.

Comment: What should I use instead of the onload function?

Answer (score 1):

Have you already check your conditions or try to place the console.log in various parts of your code? Maybe it's an issue with event firing. I've tried to run you regex with my console I guess it works smoothly.

[regex result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el6xz.png)

Comment: Yeah I added the console.log before my ```regex``` it triggers it is probably a problem with my conditional but I dont know what it is

Comment: Does the console.log('invalid file') runs? If yes, Then it will never return true. Becaude the .test() method only returns true or false. You don't need to add `== N` if you wish to test your regex