# MEAN stack async call seems to be getting fired before a response is received

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I'm making a request to a node.js server from an Angular application and need to wait until I get a response from the server before continuing. There seems to be something wrong with my async call, but I can't figure out what it is.

This is my login component:

```
  onLogin() {
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      console.log(this.form);
      console.log('Form invalid');
      return;
    }
    this.isLoading = true;
    const findUserType = () => {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(this.authService.getUserType(this.form.value.username));
      });
    };
    async function asyncCall() {
      console.log('getting user type');
      const result = await findUserType().then(userType => {
        console.log(userType);
      });
    }
```

Making a request through the authservice:

```
  getUserType(username: string) {
    this.http.post<{ message: string; }>(
      'http://localhost:3000/api/user/find-user',
      { username }
    )
    .subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response.message);
      return response.message;
    });
  }
```

Which is grabbing the data from nodejs:

```
router.post('/find-user', (req, res, next) => {
  function checkHauler() {HaulerUser.countDocuments({ username: req.body.username }, function (err, count) {
      if (count > 0) {
        return res.status(200).json({
          message: 'isHauler'
        })
      }
    });
  }
  function checkAbf() {AbfUser.countDocuments({ username: req.body.username }, function (err, count) {
      if (count > 0) {
        return res.status(200).json({
          message: 'isAbf'
        })
      }
    });
  }
  function checkUtility() {UtilityUser.countDocuments({ username: req.body.username }, function (err, count) {
      if (count > 0) {
        return res.status(200).json({
          message: 'isUtility'
        })
      }
    });
  }
  Promise.all([checkHauler(), checkAbf(), checkUtility()])
    .then(() => {
      console.log('done')
  })
```

This is what shows in my console:

```
getting user type
undefined
result: undefined

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
    at setFieldValue (onloadwff.js:71)
    at HTMLFormElement.formKeydownListener (onloadwff.js:71)

isAbf
```

I'm very new to all of this and any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You're combining observables and promises, which will make the concepts so much more tricky to grasp if you're just starting out.

My recommendation is to make `getUserType` return a promise, like this:

```
  getUserType(username: string) {
    return this.http.post(
      'http://localhost:3000/api/user/find-user',
      { username }
    ).toPromise();
  }
```

Then in your other function, you can log the results of this POST request:

```
    async yourAsyncCall() {
      console.log('getting user type');
      const result = await this.authService.getUserType('blahh insert test username here');
      console.log('post api result', result);
    }
```

Notice that I've removed the use of `.then` in favor of async/await.  Hackernoon wrote a [good article](https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9) about why async/await makes promises so much easier to work with.

Comment: This makes sense, but now it's telling me authService is undefined

Comment: Are you injecting the auth service in your component's constructor?  Are you also including the service in your app/feature module?  The code in your question doesn't show this.

Comment: Yup. It works outside of the function in the same component, but not inside the function

Comment: Hmm, why are you nesting the functions that way?  Just break it out into its own function at the component level.  I wrote another [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101360/console-log-not-working-when-testing-regex/60101959#60101959) that touches on why `this` can sometimes be tricky since its value is determined by how a function is called (runtime binding). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this